# Moment of inertia of rectangular lamina

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

For calculating the moment of inertia of a rectangular lamina, we take thin strips of rectangles and then integrate considering two axes. There we take a strip at a distance $x$ from the center of gravity and this distance is the perpendicular distance to the thin rectangle. But moment of inertia is defined for point masses. I already raised a question on MOI before but that was for ring and I got my answer on that. But here how do we calculate the MOI of that thin strip using the definition of MOI from point masses?

Comment: I guess you can do this using the same method if your previous question was solved. (Previous question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/658475/)

Comment: Hmm i understood the first poster's answer that since the radius is constant,therfore all the small masses are contributing to the total mass giving the desired result.But here the distance is not fixed as you can see perpendicular distance is being taken here. That's why i am perplexed.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter whether we are taking wrt x or y axis since that doesn't seem to have an overwhelming amount of relevance to my actual doubt.

Comment: If you want some sort of intuitive idea, think of each strip as a rod and use parallele axis theorem to understand how they might contribute to the MoI. Unfortunately this will only get you so far as you must at some point dive into the integral definition of MoI

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same idea as in the linked answer to show that the moment of inertia of any object whose mass is at distance exactly $R$ from the axis is $MR^2$. Therefore it holds not only for a ring of radius $R$, but for any subset of a ring such as a union of circular arcs of radius $R$.

Let $a$ and $b$ be the sides of our rectangular lamina with $a > b$ and let $M$ be its mass. We can assume that $a$ is the horizontal side and $b$ the vertical side. I'm assuming that the axis is perpendicular to the rectangle and goes through its center. Notice that you can decompose the rectangle as a union of objects of the above type. Namely, for any $r \in \left[0,\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}2\right]$ look at the circle centered at the axis of radius $r$ and take only those parts which intersect the rectangle; for a fixed $r$ you will get a circle or a union of circular arcs.

We can hence calculate $$I_{\text{rectangle}} =\int_{r=0}^{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}dI_{\text{rectangle $\cap$ ring}}(r) = \int_{r=0}^{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}m(r)r^2\,dr$$
where $m(r)$ is the mass of the ring-like object at radius $r$. It remains to simply calculate its mass for any fixed $r$. Denote $\sigma = \frac{M}{ab}$ the areal density of our rectangle. Clearly, the mass of our ring-like object is then simply
$$m(r) = \sigma\cdot \text{area of the object} = \sigma\,dr\cdot\text{length of the object}$$
since its thickness is infinitesimal. Hence it remains to calculate its length. There are three cases:

1. If $r \in \left[0,\frac{b}2\right]$ then the ring of radius $r$ lies entirely inside the rectangle so its length is simply $2r\pi$.
2. If $r \in \left[\frac{b}2,\frac{a}2\right]$ then the ring of radius $r$ intersects our rectangle in two circular arcs of equal length (left and right). Half of the central angle of one arc is given by the relation $\sin\phi = \frac{b}{2r}$ so by symmetry, the entire length is
   $$4\arcsin\left(\frac{b}{2r}\right).$$
3. If $r \in \left[\frac{a}2,\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}2\right]$ then the ring of radius $r$ intersects our rectangle in four circular arcs of equal length (one near each corner of the rectangle). Similary to the last example, one can see that the entire length is
   $$4\arcsin\left(\frac{b}{2r}\right) - 4\arccos\left(\frac{a}{2r}\right).$$

Plugging this in, we get
$$I_{\text{rectangle}} =\int_{r=0}^{\frac{b}2}2r^3\pi\sigma\,dr +  \int_{r=\frac{b}2}^{\frac{a}2} 4\arcsin\left(\frac{b}{2r}\right)r^2\sigma\,dr + \int_{r=\frac{a}2}^{\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}2 } 4\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{b}{2r}\right) - \arccos\left(\frac{a}{2r}\right)\right)r^2\sigma\,dr.$$

These integrals are not easy but they can be calculated using e.g. Wolfram Mathematica, reproducing the standard result listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia).